# Problem with CvBridge and ArUco opencv modules combined with ROS kinetic in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, opencv, ros, aruco

I'm working on a project with a drone, which has its drivers that only work with ROS kinetic, this limits me to ubuntu 16.x and ROS kinetic. I use python 3.5 but when I try to convert the images from *sensor_msgs/Image* type extracted from the ROS topic to an image able to be processed with OpenCV, I need to use CvBridge. I am able to see the image with `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/topic` or using `rviz`, so the image is coming correctly from the topic.

The problem is that I need `aruco` module to be imported to process the image.
`CvBridge` gives me errors if I use opencv version 3 or greater, but when I install `opencv` 2.4.9 and set default python to 2.7 I can use it but then the error comes from no `aruco` module existent, I tried to build the 2.4.9 version with the contrib modules manually but it doesn't work either.

So if anyone knows how to use the `CvBridge` or a similar module with the newest version of `opencv`, the one that is installed using the command `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

I would be grateful to any useful answer.

I can provide more info if it is required or the question not understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Question solved. I don't know exactly why or how, but after I made a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on another disk, installed ros kinetic following this:

http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

and then the drivers of the drone with this:

https://bebop-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

and everything works fine with the default opencv 3.3.1-dev version that comes with te OS.